# Expanding People and Groups Column using React SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

Being new to SPFx , I've not able to retrieve values from people and group **Attendee** column

Below are the steps I followed

Defined Attendee in the below interface

```
export interface IListItem{
  
    CourseName:{ID:Number; Title:String;};
    Attendee:{ID:Number; Title:String;};
    Status: {ID:Number; Title:String;};
    Completed: Date;   
  }
 
import { IListItem } from './ListItemInterface';
 
export class EntityListItems{
  
  public CourseNameID:Number;
  public CourseNameTitle:String;
  public Completed:Date;
  public AttendeeID: Number; 
  public AttendeeTitle:String;
  public StatusID: Number; 
  public StatusTitle:String;
 
  constructor(item: IListItem){
    
    this.CourseNameID = item.CourseName.ID;
    this.CourseNameTitle = item.CourseName.Title;
    this.Completed = item.Completed;
    this.AttendeeID = item.Attendee.ID;
    this.AttendeeTitle = item.Attendee.Title;
    this.StatusID = item.Status.ID;
    this.StatusTitle = item.Status.Title;
 
  }
}
```

Below is the rest call , where I have expanded the column as shown below

```
sp.web.lists
.getByTitle("SampleList")
.items.select(
  "*",
  "CourseName/Title",
  "Attendee/Title",
  "Attendee/ID",
  "Status/Title",
  "Completed",
  "AttachmentFiles"
)
.expand("CourseName", "Attendee", "Status", "AttachmentFiles")
.filter("Status/Title eq 'Not Started'")
.top(4999)
.orderBy("Created", false)
.get()
.then((response) => {
  let getdetails = response.map((item) => new EntityListItems(item));
});
```

While debugging , I get undefined for Attendee on People Picker Column as shown below

[image]

Not sure if I am missing out on something and would appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please try this and check what you get in browser console?

`response.map((item) => console.log(item));`

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am getting the Attendee array to display in the console , so how to construct the interface?

I have mentioned the structure of my interface in the question , can you please suggest changes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Variable **u** is defined. Otherwise it would make sense that all your Attendee values are undefined

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I have edited the code and removed the usage of the variable u , However that doesn't seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your interfaces like below:

Add new interface for holding person information:

```
export interface PersonItem {
    ID:Number;
    Title:String;
}
```

Add array of persons to your `IListItem` interface:

```
export interface IListItem {
    CourseName: {ID:Number; Title:String;};
    Attendee: PersonItem[];
    Status: {ID:Number; Title:String;};
    Completed: Date;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Ganesh

What changes are required for the EntitiesListItems Class as shown below?

import { IListItem } from './ListItemInterface';
 
export class EntityListItems{
  
  
  public AttendeeID: Number; 
  public AttendeeTitle:String;

 
  constructor(item: IListItem){
    
    
    this.AttendeeID = item.Attendee.ID;
    this.AttendeeTitle = item.Attendee.Title;
 
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could print the item to check the value in it.And check if the type of item is IListItem.